# How to reverse the Lastname,Firstname of an expression inside a Cognos data item?

Tags: oracle11g, cognos-10

I created a list report in Cognos and the LAST NAME column is currently in Lastname,Firstname order, with no spaces except for Firstname with a second name included.

From this current set-up

```
    LAST_NAME COLUMN
    Morello,Mortel     
    Chopra,Deepak      
    Fothergill,Mike Edward   
    Smith,David
```

I'm hoping to get this result.

```
    NEW DATA ITEM
    Mortel Morello
    Deepak Chopra
    Mike Edward Fothergill
    David Smith
```

I tried using a substring function but it does not work.

```
substring(LAST_NAME, position(',', LAST_NAME)+1, 
inStr(LAST_NAME, ' ',position(',', LAST_NAME)+1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
substring([Last Name],position(',',[Last Name])+1) 
+ ' ' +
substring([Last Name],1,position(',',[Last Name])-1)
```

Comment: Your answer runs a lot faster when I'm running the query in View Tabular Data. Thank you!!